# Use Purrr to filter and estimate the same model specification multiple times

Tags: r, purrr, tidymodels

I have a dataset that I want to use to estimate some linear models. The data can be replicated with the code below.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  location= c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5), rep("C",5), 
              rep("D",5), rep("E",5), rep("F",5),
              rep("G",5), rep("H",5), rep("I",5),
              rep("J",5)),
  year = rep(c(2017,2018,2019,2020,2021),10),
  w = rnorm(50),  
  x = rnorm(50),
  y = rnorm(50),
  z = rnorm(50)
)
```

It would have the following look

| location | year | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017 | -0.560 | 0.253 | -0.710 | 0.788 |
| A | 2018 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |
| A | 2019 | 1.56 | -0.0429 | -0.247 | 0.332 |
| A | 2020 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |
| A | 2021 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |
| B | 2017 | -0.560 | 0.253 | -0.710 | 0.788 |
| B | 2018 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |
| B | 2019 | 1.56 | -0.0429 | -0.247 | 0.332 |
| B | 2020 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |
| B | 2021 | -0.230 | -0.0285 | 0.257 | 0.769 |

I want to run models with two dependent variables (*w* and *x*) using *y* and *z* as explanatory variables for all the years separately and get the distribution of the parameter estimates. Basically,in the end I would like to have a dataframe for the estimates across the years for each dependent variable.

The approach I initially considered involves running the models individually, duplicating the same steps for each, and then combining the rows from these separate dataframes. However, I want to use purrr's funcationality to write an efficient code.

Here is what I have coded so far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

dependent_vars<- c("w","x")
model_1 <- reformulate(termlabels = c("y","z"), response = dependent_vars[1] )

lm_mod <- linear_reg()

lm_fit_2017_w <- 
  lm_mod %>% 
  fit(model_1, data = df %>% filter (year==2017)) %>%
  tidy() %>% 
  mutate(year=2017, response= dependent_vars[1])

# Repeat this for the rest of the years as well as for x and finally bind the rows
```

I have come across some resources dealing with the same type of problem but with just different dependent variables or predicators [stackoverlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005446/using-purrr-to-fit-many-models-using-tidymodels) & [blog](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2019/07/22/automate-model-fitting-with-loops/).

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first generate a data.frame with all possible combinations of the years and dependent variables, and then use this with `pmap` which can take two or more input variables at the same time.

I've attached an untested solution with `tidymodels` (can't install it at the moment) and one without that is tested:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  location= c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5), rep("C",5), 
              rep("D",5), rep("E",5), rep("F",5),
              rep("G",5), rep("H",5), rep("I",5),
              rep("J",5)),
  year = rep(c(2017,2018,2019,2020,2021),10),
  w = rnorm(50),  
  x = rnorm(50),
  y = rnorm(50),
  z = rnorm(50)
)

dependent_vars<- c("w","x")
years <- unique(df$year)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

possible_combinations <- expand.grid(year = years, dependent_var = dependent_vars,
                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

possible_combinations %>% 
  pmap(function(year, dependent_var) {
    data_model <- df %>% 
      filter(year == year)
    model_formula <- as.formula(paste0(dependent_var, " ~ y + z"))
    res <- lm(model_formula, data = data_model)
    tibble(res = list(res), year = year, dependent_var = dependent_var)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()

library(tidymodels)

lm_mod <- linear_reg()

possible_combinations %>% 
  pmap(function(year, dependent_var) {
    data_model <- df %>% 
      filter(year == year)
    model_formula <- as.formula(paste0(dependent_var, " ~ y + z"))
    lm_mod %>% 
      fit(model_formula, data = data_model) %>% 
      tidy() %>% 
      mutate(year = year, dependent_var = dependent_var)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @starja. I was exactly looking for such a solution. I couldn't quite figure what map function to use. *pmap* it is.